# Write multiple events for a single element

Tags: javascript

I have a multiple events on an elements :

```
var paragraphe = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
paragraphe.onclick = function(ev) {
    ev.target.style.color = "lime";
}
paragraphe.onmouseover = function(ev){
    ev.target.style.color = "red";
}
paragraphe.ondblclick = function(ev){
    ev.target.style.color = 'navy';
}
```

I want to create does events witout repeating the element each time, what I mean is something like this :

```
paragraphe
.onclick = function(ev) {
    ev.target.style.color = "lime";
}
.onmouseover = function(ev){
    ev.target.style.color = "red";
}
.ondblclick = function(ev){
    ev.target.style.color = 'navy';
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: You won't be able to unless you create your own wrapper function. Why does this matter anyways?

Comment: @MAJDOU Aimad If you are going to accept a jQuery answer then please be sure to add the jQuery tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ian said, this type of chaining is not available as standard without writing a wrapper. But on a browser that supports [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (IE9+) you could add a wrapper like this.

HTML

```
<p>Something</p>
```

Javascript

```
Node.prototype.addEventListener = (function (addEventListener) {
    return function () {
        addEventListener.apply(this, arguments);

        return this;
    };
}(Node.prototype.addEventListener));

document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    ev.target.style.color = "lime";
}, false).addEventListener('mouseover', function (ev) {
    ev.target.style.color = "red";
}, false).addEventListener('dblclick', function (ev) {
    ev.target.style.color = 'navy';
}, false);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/D8a4X/)

It is also possible to write a function to work with `on + eventName` (of course jQuery and other have already done this) for browsers that don't support it.

@Ian said

> Why does this matter anyways?

A good question.

And here is a possible solution for browsers that do not support `addEventListener` (this does not take into consideration older browser known bugs)

Javascript

```
Node.prototype.assignEvent = (function () {
    return function (type, listener) {
        var previousListener = this['on' + type];

        if (typeof previousListener === 'function') {
            this['on' + type] = function(evt) {
                listener(evt);
                previousListener(evt)
            };
        } else {
            this['on' + type] = listener;
        }

        return this;
    };
}());

document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].assignEvent('click', function (ev) {
    ev.target.style.color = "lime";
}).assignEvent('mouseover', function (ev) {
    ev.target.style.color = "red";
}).assignEvent('dblclick', function (ev) {
    ev.target.style.color = 'navy';
});
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3Qqs2/)

Finally you could combine both of the above examples in to a single one, that way take advantage of `addEventListener` on modern browsers while fall back to `on + eventName` for older ones.

Answer (score 1):

Chaining like this is not possible in Javascript without some extra-work. You could chain your eventhandler with jQuery like this

```
$('#foo').on('mouseenter', function(){
  // code for mouseenter
}).on('mouseleave', funciton(){
  // code for mouseleave
}).on('click', function(){
  // code for click
}).on('dblclick', function(){
  // code for doubleclick
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with JQuery:

```
var paragraphe=$("p");

paragraphe
.click(function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).css("color","lime");
})
.mouseover(function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).css("color","red");
})
.dblclick(function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).css("color","navy");
});
```